# Delete a specific string from a file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Title says it all, I have a file called `test.txt` with these contents:

```
Hello from th [BACK]e
This i [BACK]s line two.
```

Here, `[BACK]` is just a visible representation of the backspace. So a `i [BACK]s` would mean `is`. Because a backspace is implemented after a `space` and `i`.

So basically, at the click of a button, i should be able to access this file and remove ALL strings containing the word `[BACK]`-1. -1 implemented because a `[BACK]` means a backspace and is used to remove the last string before the word `[BACK]`.

## EDIT:

This time i replaced `[BACK]`  with `[SDRWUE49CDKAS]`. Just to make it a unique string. I also tested on another file. This time a `.html` with following contents:

```
Alpha, Brav [SDRWUE49CDKAS]o, Charlie, Dr [SDRWUE49CDKAS][SDRWUE49CDKAS]elta, Echo.
//         ^^Implementing "backspace"    ^^Here doing it double because we made a mistake in spelling "Delta"
//These sentences should be Alpha, Bravo, Charlie, Delta, Echo
```

Did some experimenting and tested it out with this code:

```
        string s = File.ReadAllText(path2html);
        string line = "";
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(path2html);
        if (contents.Contains("[SDRWUE49CDKAS]"))
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path2html);
            s = s.Remove(s.LastIndexOf(line + "[SDRWUE49CDKAS]") - 2, 15);
            sw.WriteLine(s);
            sw.Close();
        }
```

The edited code above will give me an output of actually deleting `[SDRWUE49CDKAS]` but not exactly how i wanted it to be:

```
Alpha, BraS]o, Charlie, DS]elta, Echo.
```

This really caused some confusion with the testing. And also not to mention that i had to run this code 3 times, because we had 3 x `[SDRWUE49CDKAS]`. So a loop will do good. I checked out a bunch of similar problems on the web, but couldn't find a one working. I'm tryna test out [this one](https://p2p.wrox.com/general-net/30984-c-read-text-file-delete-string.html) too. But it's using a `StreamReader` and a `StreamWriter` at the same time. Or maybe i should make a copy the original, and make a temp file?

Comment: LastIndexOf gives the *start* index of the last *occurrence* of the search string, not the end-index

Comment: well, removing data from file is not a trivial task. Actually file should be overwritten to do the remove operation. So, basically, you have to read file to the memory (or create temp file copy), read data from file copy (memory) and write to the file with original name. To replace the marker string and one char before you can use regex replace with `.\[BACK\]` pattern or to use the `string.IndexOf` and `string.Substring` in a loop to find the pattern and cut string starting from `pattern's index - 1` and `pattern length + 1`. Also it would be nice to add out-of bound checks.

Comment: @oleksa Thank you for clarifying that, i was just testing it out. However, this is quite confusing to implement. I've been randomly testing it out with the `remove` function. Please take a look at my edit up above.

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = "i [BACK]s";
s = s.Remove(s.IndexOf("[BACK]")-1, 1 + "[BACK]".Length);
```

result is "is".

Explanation:

- Find the start-index of `[Back]`
- Go back one position to start at the char before
- Remove from there that extra char + the marker chars

But there are several issues:

- This assumes that that search string is not at the start of that string (there is a char to remove)
- Plus it only removes the first occurrence so you will have to repeat this until all are removed
- And it doesn't handle "surrogate pairs"

Comment: Currently testing this out. Seems to stand out from the rest.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex.  You may have multiple spaces or no space is it is at the beginning of the line

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 
                "Hello from th [BACK]e\n" +
                "This i [BACK]s line two.\n";

            string pattern = @"\s*\[BACK\]";
            string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: this code removes all spaces before [BACK]. But must remove **any one** character before [BACK] as OP said `remove ALL strings containing the word [BACK]-1. -1 implemented because a [BACK] means a backspace `

Comment: Then remove the asterisk after the s in the pattern.